# Put last image to be displayed underneath the first image with <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the last image (2nd duck) to be displayed underneath the first image (cat). Is this possible with `li` tag?

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelhands/hg7ow0ug/)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  padding 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/21/b1/59/21b159ed8487d01f4ea52913804b870d--chocolate-labs-chocolate-peanut-butter.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg" style="float: left;"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add clear both property to every third element of your list.. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/wfmyso8w/)

```
ul li:nth-child(3n + 1){
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @RenzoCC ah sorry I didn't explain very well. I would like the image to fit in the space to the left of the portrait image

Comment: "Fourth" is spelled f-o-u-r-t-h.

Answer (score 0):

By default list items are displayed under each other.
I believe you use Bootstrap, the classes on the `li` make them display next to each other.

Anyway, to display it under the first Duck, use `style="clear:both"` on the list item:

```
<div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"></li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/21/b1/59/21b159ed8487d01f4ea52913804b870d--chocolate-labs-chocolate-peanut-butter.jpg"></li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg"></li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="clear: both;"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg"></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

[updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg7ow0ug/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would it be more achievable to do this if I changed them all to divs?

Comment: Sure, could also be done with a paragraph, a span, or whatever you want... I believe that's beside the point, isn't it...?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is how do I get an image to occupy the space underneath the cat and to the left of the dog haha

Comment: I am trying to build a responsive gallery and I can get around this issue by simple putting portrait images on the left side of the screen but this comes with some other issues. So this is the last piece of my puzzle I guess... Here is my gallery example
https://michael-hands.github.io/jennielouise/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is :
The dog's picture height is higher than your others images, so visually the error is understandable. So your code is working, ducks are under cat and dog's pictures respectively.

If you want the "last" duck to be under the cat, you just have to switch the last duck with the before-last duck.

I really suggest you to check the [Boostrap 3 documentation](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/#grid) in order to understand all the grid concepts.

Comment: what about this example... https://michael-hands.github.io/jennielouise/gallery.html
Is there a way to have the portrait image in the center column and have the same grid effect?